# A confusion over a concurrent architecture concept

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have basic idea about concurrency but I have a confusion about the following architecture. I think it is concurrent but my colleague thinks it is not. The architecture is as follows:

I have multiple robots which publish its data to its individual gateways and there's another java service which listens on the gateways. The service creates a new thread to listen to each gateway.

My understanding is that the service is performing concurrent execution but my colleague says this is not concurrent as concurrency involves sharing of hardware.

Appreciate if some one can clarify or elaborate on this topic.

Comment: Your question is too generic and nearly off-topic (see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)) for what can be asked or not on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

> My understanding is that the service is performing concurrent execution but my colleague says this is not concurrent as concurrency involves sharing of hardware.

**TL/DR**: Words are squishy.  That's why we have code.

"Concurrent" simply means two or more things happening at the same time.  As it applies to computation, true concurrency means two or more threads of execution running at the same time, which requires *separate* hardware.  That certainly can be separate cores of the same CPU or separate CPUs in the same chassis, so that there is some degree of shared hardware.  It can also be separate cores in *different* chassis, however, such as in a computational cluster, though perhaps this is where your colleague is drawing his line.  Such a line would be pretty arbitrary, though.

In contrast, long before it was common for even servers to feature multiple CPU (core)s, many computer systems implemented one flavor or another of *multitasking*, whereby multiple tasks can all be in progress at the same time by virtue of the operating system allotting slices of CPU time to each and switching them in and out.  All modern general-purpose operating systems still do this.  On a single core, however, this provides only simulated concurrency, because at any given instant in time, only one computation is actually making progress.

Your colleague does have a point, however, that multiple, spatially distributed robots all operating at the same time without coordination is a bit beyond what people usually mean when they talk about concurrent computation.  Certainly such robots are operating concurrently, in the general-use sense of "at the same time", but it's a bit of a stretch to characterize them as participating in a concurrent *computation*.

The server that allocates a separate thread to handle communication with each robot may thereby be performing a concurrent computation.  But as long as we're splitting hairs, do recognize that communication over a single network interface is serialized, so unless your server has multiple network interfaces, the actual communication cannot be truly concurrent.  If the server is primarily just recording the data as it arrives, as opposed to incorporating it into an ongoing concurrent computation, then it would be potentially misleading to describe it as performing a concurrent operation.

Comment: A better statement would be that “concurrent” implies the absence of a chronological (or temporal) relationship. That includes the possibility of overlapping time intervals, but does not necessarily require them. The independence implies, that it doesn’t matter. In computer science, it implies that you can’t observe a relationship without proper synchronization. An action may appear to happen before or after the other, at the same time or even out of order. It includes the possibility that both actions appear to happen before (or after) the other (without proper synchronization).

Answer (score 0):

Even by your colleague's definition, this is a concurrent system since there are multiple threads executing on the hardware on which the service resides.

Comment: Multiple threads does not inherently mean concurrency.  For example, we regularly see questions here on SO about implementing multithreaded producer / consumer models in which the point is that the producer and consumer *must not* run concurrently, at least for certain parts of their respective computations.  We use mutexes, condition variables, and other synchronization aids to limit or even eliminate concurrency in those and other scenarios.

Comment: Most concurrent systems have some need for synchronization.  That doesn't change the fact that they are still concurrent systems if the threads are operating in parallel at other times, which is normally the case in today's systems on today's hardware.  Questions here regarding multithreaded systems with no concurrency at all are nearly always homework problems, intended to provide experience with threaded code rather than driven by real world needs for multiple threads.